# Call external API and send data back to connect to Django through forms/templates

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-template-filters

I am trying to use Django forms to load a template. I am able able to make an external API call and get some data back. Now, I need to use some of this external data (not form inputs) and make a Model filter within Django. Is there a way to pass data from Javascript into Django forms?

Comment: The short answer is yes. Though you need to do this with inputs. The other more popular way to do something like this would be to look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ this would allow you to send a json object back to the server and then act of the response data without submitting the form or reloading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the best way to go about this is to make an API call within Django - Vanilla JS can be used to do some fun UI stuff before hitting a form.submit(). After that, Django gets the form data back. It makes sense to make the API call within Django, so it can use the response from there to the views/models. I used the requests library to make the API call within Django.